# Received signal from channel model

Tags: digital-communications, channel

I'm struggling with this because I don't fully understand it.

My goal is to estimate a received signal that is transmitted through a channel that follow a stochastic process. My doubt is, if the PDF and its parameters that describes the behaviour of this channel is known, how can I generate the H matrix to estimate the received signal later. In my case, the channel follows a Log-Normal distribution.

$$ y \left( t \right) = x \left( t \right) * h + n \left( t \right) \tag{1} $$

I hope someone can help me a little.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear and broad. I believe you should narrow it down to something more specific because as it is written now it kind of asks to describe the content of at least half a textbook on the topic (or even more than a single textbook). You could describe what is that you don’t understand. How to add the noise, how to perform convolution, how to use the PDF of the channel, etc.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. I'm not understand how to use the PDF of the channel in order tu calculate the H matrix and calculate the received signal. If I know that the channel follows a certain probability distribution, should I calculate the H matrix with the variance? Also another thing is that, for example, if I calculate the power received with the Friis formula, the geometrical losses are present. But in this case, if I calculate either a '1' or a '0' signal with the information of the channel, I don't have this losses in someway?

Comment: I believe you should explain a bit more about what is that you don’t understand, but do it **in the question body**. This information is crucial for people to be able to help you and does not belong in comments. Furthermore, I think you should add some more information about your approach. The equation you provided does not say much, it applies equally well to both stochastic and deterministic signals/systems. So, what are your signal and noise assumptions, do you have any expectations, do you know anything about the variables, etc.?

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time with a good, accessible textbook, like any of Haykin's books on wireless.

Comment: When you say PDF of channel, what do you mean? PDF of channel noise is a Gaussian function as per your definition (AWGN). Channel ISI (h) is independent of this noise PDF. Or may be I am misinterpreting your question.

Comment: @ZaellixA Alright, thank you very much for the advice and for your reply. I'll do it. I'm sorry, I was kinda in a hurry when I wrote it.

Comment: @MBaz Thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: @Srini I'm going to use an example with free-space optical links. The beam goes through a turbulent media that it is characterized by a stadistical distribution depending of the strength of turbulence. If this is modeled for example, using a log-normal distribution, it has an associated PDF. Then in someway h = ht. So if I'm able to describe it as a Log-Normal distribution, how can I generate the H matrix?

Comment: I am new to free space models. Seehttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312324401_Free-Space_Optical_Channel_Models&ved=2ahUKEwiq4ufWr5-EAxXqJUQIHRTVDGoQFnoECCYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1ymJgwVFW9r5MIbkOZvjh2